# Symfony: How to use the @Security annotation with ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, authentication, redirect

I'd like to use the @Security annotation for controller actions which should be called by ajax requests. Problem is, if I use "form_login" for the firewall in security.yml and the the action is called by a user who is not logged in, symfony intercepts the response and sends a 302 redirect to the configured login page. Since it's an ajax request, the 302 redirect does not make sense here. Is there a (simple) way to change the behaviour of "form_login" to not send a 302 redirect but send a 401 code back to the client (ajax)? I can find a lot of information on how to overwrite the AuthenticationSuccessHandler and AuthenticationFaliureHandler for $request->isXmlHttpRequest() like: 
http://www.webtipblog.com/adding-an-ajax-login-form-to-a-symfony-project/

But that's only one part of it, this way you can avoid getting redirects when a user submits the form. But what I would like to do is sending a 401 back to the client not only when he already tries to login, but also instead of redirecting the user to a login-form URL because of a @Security annotation or "access_control" configuration.

How I can do it now:

```
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/ajax/task/save")
     */
    public function ajaxAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user) {
            // load login-form in JS code 
            return new JsonResponse(array('authenticated'=> false), 401);
        }

        // do...
    }
}
```

but what I'd like to do is:

```
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/ajax/task/save")
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
     */
    public function ajaxAction()
    {
        // do...
    }
}
```

But this way I have to make sure that not a 302 redirecting to the login-form is send to the client but something like my JsonResponse from the previous example.

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for, you should be able to create a custom exception listener that returns a JSON response based on the content-type header and whatever status code you like before Symfony redirects the user.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Comment: I wonder why there is no more straight forward solution. Intercept 302 responses created by the security framework doesn't "feel right" to me. Or is simply the form_login not suitable if communication is done by ajax calls?

Comment: The exception handler would listen to see if the exception thrown was for a non-authenticated user who was denied access (not sure of the exact symfony exception off the top of my head). If that occurs (or you could listen for all ajax requests), you can return a Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse with whatever JSON you want so that Symfony doesn't do the redirect. You wouldn't be intercepting 302 responses, you would be listening for exceptions (errors) and acting on them if needed.